# Let $a$ be an odd integer. Using induction, prove: For any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $a^{2^n}\equiv 1\mod{2^{n+2}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, modules

I'm having trouble on where to start, I'm not sure if i should express $a$ as $2n-1$ or $2n+1$, and where to go on from that

Comment: a^(2^n)≡1(mod 2^(n +2))***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For the base case, use the fact that $a^2\equiv 1\bmod 8$ for all odd $a$ (you can prove this using either of the substitutions you suggested).

For the inductive step, note that

$$\frac{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}{a^{2^n}-1}=a^{2^n}+1$$

is even...

Comment: can i prove a is odd with mod 2 as well?

Comment: @Monnsom I'm not sure what you mean. What are you trying to prove is odd?

Comment: A is an odd integer

Comment: @Monnsom Isn't the fact that $a$ is odd assumed?

Comment: Although it is assumed a is odd, if i use the hint as part of my proof, then we must explain where we get a^2≡1 (mod 8) since he did not state that as a fact in class yet.

Comment: @Monnsom Then you should prove $a^2\equiv 1\mod{8}$ for $a$ odd yourself as part of the proof. It's not difficult; just expand $(2k+1)^2$ and consider what happens if $k$ is odd or even.